# Multiple Edittext with Buttons onClickListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

Currently I am working on an app that has somewhat of a basic calculator layout and functions. I have 8 edittext and a grid of 9 buttons. With the onClicklistener method is there a better way of handling this instead of nesting a long if or switch statement for each Edittext?

```
private View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId() /*to get clicked view id**/) {
            case R.id.btn_1:

                if edt_1.hasFocus() {
                     edt_1 = btn_1.getText()
                }

                   if edt_2.hasFocus() {
                     edt_2 = btn_1.getText()
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btn_2:

                 if edt_1.hasFocus() {
                     edt_1 = btn_1.getText()
                }

                   if edt_2.hasFocus() {
                     edt_2 = btn_1.getText()
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

I was thinking maybe it would be better to use a hasFocus() method and listen for clicks from there or a while loop, then maybe pass a variable?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/. It will give you possibility to annotate method to onClick of given view.

Comment: A faster approach would be set TAG value to the buttons and use a same ClickListener function for all buttons. Then, inside the click function, get the TAG value to the specific edittext.

Comment: @ Atish A Thanks worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

Hear is a way where you can small your code. just add android:onClick="onClick" in every button of your grid layout and do following in java file,

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
       Button b=(Button)v;
       String s+=b.getText();
    }
```

This two line get text from your button and set to the String s.

if you want to create calculator that function real-time calculation like this calculator

APK:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androchunk.calculator

then you can find free source code of calculator project as well as tutorial video that help you to create calculator and understand working of calculator.

Tutorial videos:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdMmtAIsH0KYiKrdpbzat6t96Nb1_k3_1